# Excel: How do I reference an entire row except for a couple of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

I want to be able to sum together the values of an entire row except for the first 2 cells. So something like this:

`=sum(A3:A*infinity*)`

How do I do this?

Comment: You may need to edit your question or your example. You wish to reference an entire row but your example sums a column of data.

Comment: The best answer to this question is here: https://superuser.com/a/1259946/342034. Note that I mean specifically the answer I linked to, by BBK. Don't scroll up and look for the accepted answer or the most popular answers. BBK's answer has only two upvotes as of this writing, but it's really the only truly correct answer to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting whole column except first X (header) cells in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/88449/selecting-whole-column-except-first-x-header-cells-in-excel)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something similar has been asked before and I'll repeat [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/88449/selecting-whole-column-except-first-x-header-cells-in-excel/88601#88601): just put:

```
=sum(a3:a1048576)
```

because that's the max number of cells per column / row in Office 2007 and 2010. (65536 is max for before 2007.) (For columns, the max column name is XFD in 2007 and 2010, and IV before 2007.)

Comment: I guess this is the only way to do it if the formula itself is in the same row. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Add up everything and then take away the ones you don't want to include:

```
=SUM(A:A)-A1-A2
```

Edit:

As josmh has pointed out, the formula above will fail with an error if A1 or A2 are non numeric - but the following will work:

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUM(A1,A2)
```

or

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUM(A1:A2)
```

or (for a bit of fun!)

```
=SUM(A:A,(-1*(SUM(A1))),(-1*SUM((A2))))
```

These work because the SUM function ignores non-numeric fields

Comment: This will not work if A1 or A2 are headers that hold text such as "Number of People" or "Price". Subtracting "Price" from a number causes a formula error.

Comment: Just wrap in and "IFERROR" then

Comment: Sorry if it was possibly rude how the comment came up. Upvoted now!

Comment: Will this work if the cell with the formula is on the same row, say in A1?

Comment: @Eddy No, that would create a circular reference.

Answer (score 11):

This already has several fine answers but here's a method I haven't yet seen posted:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(3:3,0,2,1,COLUMNS(3:3)-2))
```

The format is `SUM(OFFSET(Range, Rows, Cols, [Height], [Width]))`. We start with the entire range, offset it zero rows down and two columns over, set the height to 1, and set the width to its current width minus two. So long as the width adjustment is the same as the offset, it works perfectly. Here's the same idea to sum a column instead of a row: (Notice that you don't have to use the `Width` parameter because you want the same width as the original range.)

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A:A,2,0,ROWS(A:A)-2))
```

The benefit of these formulas over the currently accepted answer is that they work in any version of excel. It also won't adjust the range if you insert cells in front because it's referencing the entire row / column. You may or may not want that functionality depending on your data setup.

Comment: This is actually the best answer. It’s as close to `=sum(A3:A*infinity*)` as Microsoft Excel will permit. Unfortunately, every reference must be entered twice (one for the OFFSET function and another for the ROWS function).

Comment: This is demonstrably *not* the best answer as this formula will recalculate if a cell in an unrelated range is changed (i.e. `z50`). Thus unnecessary calculations are conducted which may not be noticeable for small files, but will can be detrimental with larger file and achieves nothing over this formula which provides the same result: `=SUM(A3:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A:A)))` but will not recalc unless a value in columns A is changed.

Answer (score 5):

I thought you could simply do the following:
    =SUM(A3:A)

**Edit**: Sorry I misread, this is for a *column*

For rows, see the approved answer.

Comment: I remember doing this in the and it worked in a past job I had, but in my copy of Office 2007 right now that notation doesn't work in formulas, or if you type it into the Name Box.

Comment: this is actually the correct answer

Comment: Doesn't like it in Excel for Mac 15.36

Comment: For Microsoft Excel 2016, it should be `=SUM(A3:A:A)`.

Comment: In Excel 2013, ``=SUM(A3:A:A)`` seems to be the same as `=SUM(A:A)`. (I’m surprised that it isn’t a syntax error.)

Comment: OP said row, not column. This answer is for columns.

Answer (score 4):

To sum an ***entire row***:

```
=sum(1:1)
```

Replace **1** with your starting **row** number and then use the autofill handle accordingly. If you drag the formula down, it'll change to "=sum(2:2)" and so on..

To sum the **entire *row*, except the first 2 columns**:

```
=sum(1:1)-sum($a1:$b1)
```

This'll help you cut down on the file size.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Excel does not have the nifty google sheets feature to write a formula as `A3:A` (for rows) or `C3:3` (for columns). While most of these answers listed will work, I would argue my below formulas are the best *technical* solutions:

### For Rows

`=SUM(A3:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A:A)))`

### For Columns (excluding A and B)

`=SUM(C3:INDEX(3:3,Columns(1:1)))`

### Why these are better TECHNICAL choices than other listed answers

---

#### `=sum(a3:a1048576)` (accepted answer)

Overall this is a decent solution however this will throw an error in Excel versions 2003 and earlier. It also will not include all rows if future Excel versions increase the row count (next jump would be to 16,777,215 rows if same method from 2003 to 2007). Admittedly, this is quite picky and most users would probably be fine using this solution, however *TECHNICALLY* it is not as dynamic as my option.

---

#### `=SUM(A:A)-A1-A2` or `=sum(1:1)-sum($a1:$b1)`

This works for summations, but this will run into trouble with other functions such as average, count, max, min. My answer will generate the proper range which can then be used for any function that uses a range input.

---

#### `=SUM(OFFSET(A:A,2,0,ROWS(A:A)-2))`

This is similar concept to my answer however `Offset` is a volatile function that should never be used if you can use index (which we can in this case). It may not make a difference if you have a small file, but using offset can reduce your performance considerably as it constantly recalculates. [This article details this issue](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-volatile-formulas/).

Like I said, all of these will probably address the issue, but I thought I'd just provide some ultra geeked out analysis (hey... what do you expect... it's an Excel question! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also select cells in a row or column by selecting the first cell and then pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> key (<kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd> or <kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd> for rows, UP ARROW or DOWN ARROW for columns).

Note If the row or column contains data, CTRL+SHIFT+ARROW key selects the row or column to the last used cell. Pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ARROW key **a second time** selects the entire row or column.

**PS.**
Is a pity that Excel does not have the same trick that **Google Sheets** has. By eg. to select from C2 to C (**infinity**), you can do there:

```
SUM(C2:2)
```

Comment: How sure are you that this works? It sure doesn't work in Excel 2013. Also, this is the same answer that [Skube](http://superuser.com/a/689233/348859) posted over 2 years ago.

Comment: It would also be nice if that worked because of consistency. If `A3:A` is a valid range, so should `A3:3` be. There must be a syntax reason why it is not allowed in Excel, and Google Sheets designers must have known what that reason was when they got started.

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, I wanted to do something similar - to sum all cells in a column between a certain cell and the cell above the place where the sum will appear. This is what I've come up:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5;COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))
```

It is not directly answering OP's question, but it could be helpful to someone.