# How to reference a row except some cells(to find maximum value from rest of the row)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

This ([Excel: How do I reference an entire row except for a couple of cells?](https://superuser.com/questions/284953/excel-how-do-i-reference-an-entire-row-except-for-a-couple-of-cells)) question has title of what I want.  However text and answers are about finding range in a column..

Detailed question.

I have series of numbers in columns D,E,F,G,H,..... to last column.(say CCC). How to find max  and fill in column C for corresponding row.

[image]

Current work around is to assume column to be AAA (or such last )and use formula as it is

```
=MAX(D2:AAA2)
```

How do I refer the really last column in the row?

Comment: Are all the rows the same length?

Comment: yes. we can assume so

Comment: I'm very lost as to what the problem is... What cells do you want to exclude? Why doesn't `MAX(D2:AAA2)` work?

Comment: How do I refer the last column in the row? Tomorrow if there is data beyond AAA2 say at BBB2?)  it will not come in query.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. So, is your question how to reference columns past `AAA` ?

Comment: I will accept that as answer.  I wanted to know if there was any other  function/variable to refer this last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to reference ZZZ, as far as I know, Excel 2010 only goes up to `XFD` as the furthest (maximum) column

I can use the MAX as you described

```
=MAX(D2:XFD2)
```