# How does Excel's INDEX know to use REFERENCE form?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was trying to build a formula that can SPILL to return all unique text rows in a column apart from the first (header).

I found a solution at https://superuser.com/a/1259946/1137272 which works and gives me what I need using the INDEX function - which is great and I've successfully translated it from the SUM() application described into my application with UNIQUE(), but I'm having trouble understanding how it achieves the result.

The solution as provided is

`=SUM(A2:INDEX(A:A, ROWS(A:A)))`

in my case this translates to the functioning but more complex:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('SheetName'!D2:INDEX('SheetName'!D:D,ROWS('SheetName'!D:D)),ISTEXT('SheetName'!D2:INDEX('SheetName'!D:D,ROWS('SheetName'!D:D)))))`

I follow that ROWS(A:A) gives the last row number (1048576 in my case).
INDEXing by N into an array returns the Nth value in the array, so I would assume INDEX would return the value of A1048576 - in my case an empty cell, and the SUM formula would expand to SUM(A2:[blank]) or SUM(A2:0) and thus give an error.

However, this isn't what happens - apparently there's also a 'reference' form of the INDEX function and somehow INDEX knows to return the cell reference rather than the value of the cell, but I don't understand how this is triggered. It looks to me like the syntax for both forms is exactly the same:
`INDEX(array/reference, row_num, [optional_arguments])`

In cases like this where an array and reference look identical (A:A), how does it know when to return the value and when to return the cell reference?

Answer (score 0):

> In cases like this where an array and reference look identical (A:A), how does it know when to return the value and when to return the cell reference?

As stated [here](https://exceljet.net/functions/index-function#:%7E:text=It%27s%20important%20to%20note%20that%20the%20INDEX%20function%20returns%20a%20reference%20as%20a%20result.):

> It's important to note that the INDEX function returns a reference as a result.

The formula mentioned by the OP is  `=SUM(A2:INDEX(A:A, ROWS(A:A)))`. Let start only with the INDEX part (`INDEX(A:A, ROWS(A:A))`). If this part was the only part of the formula, INDEX would reference A1048576 and would return its value. You may consider this part of the formula to be analogous to `=A1048576`.

In the case of the whole formula (`SUM(A2:INDEX(A:A, ROWS(A:A)))`, INDEX is combined with SUM function. Thus, as already mentioned the INDEX function returns a reference, when `INDEX(A:A, ROWS(A:A))`  is processed by Excel, the reference is A1048576. Excel use this reference in the SUM function. Thus, you will have `SUM(A2:A1048576)`.

Good rule of thumb to differentiate between array and reference forms,  if INDEX function is used with:

- another function as the example above, then it's the reference form.
- multiple ranges as its first argument, then it's the reference form.
- only one range as its first argument, then it's the array form.

Comment: Thanks - your ExcelJet link explains the functioning of INDEX a bit better than the reference I was using. 

I'm not entirely convinced by your rule-of-thumb though - INDEX paired with another function doesn't normally mean reference form - for example LEFT(INDEX(A:A,2),1)
 is going to return the first character of the contents of A2, not the first character of the cell reference of A2 ("A")

My reading now is that under-the-hood INDEX is *always* returning the reference - it just happens in most cases it's parsed to resolve to the value.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure when a cell reference will be parsed to a value and when it's just used as a reference. So far I've seen examples where it's part of an array definition (either side of a colon), or when it's part of the CELL() function - but everything else I've seen it resolves to a value.

Comment: @JNeilson "INDEX paired with another function doesn't normally mean reference form" The reference is returned first, then the value (the content of the reference) will be returned (as last resort). Regarding `LEFT(INDEX(A:A,2),1`, `INDEX(A:A,2)` returns the reference meaning A2 for the LEFT function to process. The formula is now `LEFT(A2,1)`. Only then is the value of A2 processed by the LEFT function and returns the first character.